# How to configure unit tests with an IoC container in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, unity-container

I have configured Unity in my ASP.NET application and the configuration is loaded when the first request is received in Application_BeginRequest. then the Unity container is stored in the Global.ascx as a property so that my other class can access it:

```
public static IUnityContainer ContainerHolder { get; set; }

IUnityContainer IContainerAccessor.Container
{
    get { return ContainerHolder; }
}
```

ContainerHolder, holds the container instance across application and Container property allows access to this property in each session.

Then I have a UnityLocator class which enables me access this property across the application:

```
public static class UnityLocator
    {        
        private static IUnityContainer Container
        {
            get
            {
                return ((IContainerAccessor)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance).Container;
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine!

I have also a method to access the instance from Unity:

```
UnityLocator.GetInstance<IThemeManager>();

    protected Repository(ICustomCacheManager customCacheManager)
    {
        this.Cache = customCacheManager;
    }

    protected Repository()
        : this(UnityLocator.GetInstance<ICustomCacheManager>())
    {

    }
```

this has been used in my app so that I can retrieve an existing instance from Unity so that I can inject it to other classes. For example my view (asp.net page) injects this to its Presenter class as a dependency.

Now, I'd like to configure my Unit tests to run.

How could I do that?! global.ascx doesn't exist there obviously so I thought I should create a BaseTest class and let all my tests inherit it. then at the constructor of this BaseTest class, I build up my instances. Is it the right way to do it?

How to configure unit tests with Unity now?

Thanks

UPDATE:
UnityLocator.GetInstance added.

Comment: Perhaps an overview of the problem that IoC solves would be a good start here. If you understand the problem domain then it'll make more sense of why you don't need to concern yourself with the IoC container in your unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably using the global application class for storing the service locator was not a good idea. Why don't you use the built-in ServiceLocator class? It is available from anywhere in the code and doesn't depend on global application / HttpContext.

Whether or not using the container in unit tests is another story. Personally I am not against it as long as you put stub implementations of your services into the container.

Edit: the way to configure your container using ServiceLocator:

```
    private void ConfigureUnity()
    {
        UnityServiceLocator locator = new UnityServiceLocator( ConfigureUnityContainer() );
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider( () => locator );
    }

    private IUnityContainer ConfigureUnityContainer()
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        // this loads container's configuration, comment or uncomment
        container.LoadConfiguration();

        return container;
    }
```

You can then access the container from within the locator like:

```
var container = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUnityContainer>();
```

Comment: And where can we find this `ServiceLocator` class? You say it's built-in. Built-in to what? .NET? ASP.NET?

Comment: thanks, I'm going to replace my UnityLocator with the built-in ServiceLocator: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2009/05/12/servicelocator-and-unity-be-careful.aspx

Comment: the only problem I have with your suggestion is that my below method won't work in this case: public static void InjectDependencies<T>(T existingType)
        {
            Container.BuildUp(existingType);
        } that is to inject dependencies of a type.

Comment: ServiceLocator doesn't give me access to the Container; how would you resolve this?

Comment: You should be able to get one from the container with `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUnityContainer>()`.

Comment: @William: Why do you think you need access to the container from within the application. Try to prevent this. In most cases it's a problem in your design.

Comment: @Steven, the reason was that I had a BasePage class from which all my pages inherit. In this class, there are properties such as ILogger which should be injected to and I was using Container.Build(type) method. I removed that now and I just simply inject those classes using e.g. ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ILogger>().

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't worry about accessing your IoC container. That is a violation of Unit Tests.

Unit tests you should not worry about any concrete implementation or dependency (other than the class under test).

To me, having your IoC globally available is a bad design choice. You should have your dependencies injected via properties or constructors.

Comment: what do you mean? how to configure and run my unit tests now?

Comment: @William - are you using mvc or web forms?

Comment: web forms, mvp. I realised I'm using UnityLocator.GetInstance<T> method in my code so I'm going to refactor that and move them to the view only (pages).

Comment: why are your views that dependent on something?

Comment: I agree with Daniel that you shouldn't use the container in your unit tests. Just manually inject the dependencies in the class under test. When you have a globally configured container for all your tests, you will get yourself into a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Although having a global reference to the container is a design smell (its the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx)) it's hard to prevent this in an ASP.NET Web Forms application. In ASP.NET Web Forms I personally like to hide the container behind a `Global.BuildUp(object)` method and let my Page classes and user controls call the Global.BuildUp(this)` in their constructor and do property injection. Unfortunately, Web Forms is an ugly thing when it comes to dependency injection.

Comment: for example, in my asp.net page, page_preinit event I initialize the Presenter object this way: this._presenter = new DepartmentReportPresenter(this,
 UnityLocator.GetInstance<IRepositoryForWeekCommendingList>(),
 UnityLocator.GetInstance<IThemeManager>());

Comment: otherwise, how to create my presenter object inside my aspx page without using my UnityLocator class?!

Comment: But since you are doing MVP, in most cases, a Page classes will most of the time have a single dependency: the presenter. Two thumbs up for picking the MVP design pattern.

Comment: yeah, the injection happens from the aspx page. so I'm going to refactor it and use ServiceLocator class instead, also will refactor it so that injection happens only from the aspx page; getting interesting! any other idea?

Comment: @Steven, how would you inject dependencies of a type? I'm using Container.BuildUp(Type)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3904/discussion-between-steven-and-william)

Answer (score 1):

In your page, try doing things like this:

```
public class DepartmentReportPage : Page
{
    private readonly DepartmentReportPresenter _presenter;

    public DepartmentReportPage()
    {
        this._presenter =
            UnityLocator.GetInstance<DepartmentReportPresenter>();

        this._presenter.View = this;
    }
}
```